# Prints are Squished

Tags: marlin, pla, tronxy-x1

My printer prints stuff okay but its all squished and much shorter than the model, My z Axis Esteps is fine I checked for loose wires and overheating but I can't figure it out. My Temp is 195, .15 Layer Height, PLA, Marlin Firmware

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! We love to help, but without enough information that is very hard. Please at least add a photo that shows the problem. It sounds like the Z axis doesn't advance enough, this can be related to a driver issue (not enough current).

Comment: On an X1 straight out of the box it might also be an issue of the Z-axis binding (it should turn easily)